# How to add background image to the frame in tkinter python? Instead of background color I want an image

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, tkinter-canvas

Need to add an image as the frame background, the button quit must be on the image.I tried some codes but the image appeared as above and the frame below the image.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from PIL import ImageTk,Image


root = Tk()
root.title("Sign In")
root.geometry("600x420")

class one:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.frame = Frame(self.root, bg="light blue", width=800, height=400)
        root.geometry("800x400")
        self.header = Label(self.root, bg="blue", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 30, "bold"))
        self.header.pack(fill=X)
        self.heading = Label(self.root, text="First One", fg="white", bg="blue", font=("Times New Roman", 30, "bold"))
        self.heading.place(x=10, y=0)
        self.q = Button(self.frame, text="Quit", bg="brown", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 10), command=self.root.destroy)
        self.q.place(x=650, y=320, width=120, height=20)
        self.frame.pack()

obj = one(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hmmmm i dont think its possible to put it on a frame, instead try a `Canvas`?

Comment: Have you tried searching this site before asking? There are many questions about background images.

Answer (score 0):

In Tkinter, you can add a background image to a frame by adding a label as the frame parent. Set the label background image using PIL and set the frame background to empty string.

Try this code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = Tk()
root.title("Sign In")
root.geometry("600x420")

class one:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bgredgrad.png"))  # label image (frame background)
        self.label = Label(self.root, image = self.img, width=800, height=400)  # frame parent
        
        self.frame = Frame(self.label, bg="", width=800, height=400)  # main widget, clear background
        self.frame.place(x=0, y=0, width=800, height=400)   # required for correct z-index
        root.geometry("800x400")
        self.header = Label(self.root, bg="brown", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 30, "bold"))
        self.header.pack(fill=X)
        self.heading = Label(self.root, text="First One", bg="brown", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 30, "bold"))
        self.heading.place(x=10, y=0)
        self.q = Button(self.frame, text="Quit", bg="brown", fg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 10), command=self.root.destroy)
        self.q.place(x=650, y=320, width=120, height=20)
        self.label.pack()  # pack bottom widget

obj = one(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Output (my background)

[image: BG Image]